# libGDX using Stage and Actor produces different camera angles on desktop and Android Phone

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx

libGDX using Stage and Actor produces different camera angles on desktop and Android Phone.

Here are pictures demonstrating the problem: http://brandonyuh.minus.com/mFpdTSgN17VUq

On the desktop version, the image takes up almost all the screen. On the Android phone it only takes up a bit of the screen.

Here's the code (not my actual project but I isolated the problem):

```
package com.me.mygdxgame2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.*;
public class MyGdxGame2 implements ApplicationListener {
    private Stage stage;
    public void create() {
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.addActor(new ActorHi());
    }
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.draw();
    }
    public void dispose() {}
    public void resize(int width, int height) {}
    public void pause() {}
    public void resume() {}
    public class ActorHi extends Actor {
        private Sprite sprite;
        public ActorHi() {
            Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/hi.png"));
            texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
            sprite = new Sprite(new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 128, 128));
            sprite.setBounds(0, 0, 300.0f, 300.0f);
        }
        public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
            sprite.draw(batch);
        }
    }
}
```

hi.png is included in the above link

Thank you very much for answering my question. I've spent 3 days trying to figure it out.

Comment: You might get people who know libGDX better if you ask here instead - http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What are you passing to the `LwjglApplication` constructor in your desktop project?  And what is the resolution of your Android phone?

Answer (score 1):

```
 stage = new Stage();
```

initializes the stage with a camera that maps its viewport to the real screen resolution. If desktop and device don't have the same resolution they won't look the same.
Try setting fixed values to the stage. Use this: (you can check javadoc [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.java)

```
public void setViewport (float width, float height, boolean keepAspectRatio);
```

eg. Use some fixed value like
      setViewport (800, 600, true);

This will also fill the screen, but will always show a 800x600 world, no matter the resolution. (actually it would be "at least" 800x600 because of the keepAspectRation = true that prevents distortion)